# Mass redirect - Alternative to the .htaccess file on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently merged a few websites into one, which results in about 500 redirects being written. At the moment, these redirects are located in my `.htaccess` file. While this works, it is basically unmanageable and not very fail-safe – I don't want to imagine what happens if somebody overwrites that file.

How to properly manage such a redirect amount? Is there an alternative to using the .htaccess?

The webpage runs on a dedicated managed server, so it powers several webpages, which means I can't directly edit files like `httpd.conf`. The webpage that is need of the redirects is written in a PHP based CMS. Also, the URLs are always different, so it no possible to use patterns.

Comment: there are quite a few files that if overwritten could take down the server, i'm not sure that's really a concern. where you planing to leave the redirects forever? are you issuing an appropriate header so the new pages are indexed?

Comment: Are you using cPanel?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, the redirects should be there forever (or at least a very long time). And yes, I am doing this so that the new pages get indexed.

Comment: @BRad No, the Server is running Plesk.